# Quick way to find if a port is open in all Local Network using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, networking, system-administration

From a bash script how can I quickly find out whether a port 80 is open/listening on a server.

On all workstations is opened daemon, but sometimes it fall, how i can check all files from file if port is open, i found a way to use

```
 nc -zw3 10.101.0.13 80 && echo "opened" || echo "closed"
```

but how to use it in bulk from a file, my writed file look like:

```
10.101.0.13; 3333
10.101.0.15; 3334
10.101.0.17; 4143
10.101.0.21; 1445
10.101.0.27; 2443
10.101.0.31; 2445
10.101.0.47; 3443
10.101.0.61; 3445
```

I have to separate working one from non working, but also with all the line. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to separate working one from non working, but also with all the
>   line.

you can just loop through the file, and write the status to corresponding text files

```
sed 's/;/ /' file | while read ip other
do
        nc -zw3 $ip 80 && echo "$line" >> opened.txt || echo "$line" >> closed.txt
done
```

If you want to keep the `IP; otherstuff` format, you can use this one instead

```
while read line
do
        ip=$(sed 's/;.*//' <<<"$line")
        nc -zw3 $ip 80 && echo "$line" >> opened.txt || echo "$line" >> closed.txt
done < file
```

Comment: maybe your input file doesn't have space after `;`, I have updated my answer, should be ok now

Comment: Thank you ray, may i ask you, is there any other way instead of "sed"?? in case if the line is not only by $ip;$port but + an strings... it gives error, can i scan such lines too?

Comment: You can use `sed` `awk` to manipulate the strings. Depending on how your file looks like, there may be other better option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `bash` one liner,

```
while IFS=";" read ip port; do nc -zw3 "$ip" "$port" && echo "$ip:$port => opened" || echo "$ip:$port =>  closed"; done<'ip_list_file.txt'
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
while IFS=";" read ip port; do nc -zw3 "${ip}" "${port}" && echo "${ip}:${port} => opened" || echo "${ip}:${port} =>  closed"; done<'ip_list'
```

Comment: Thanks sat, but also get error(( `while: Expression Syntax.` and `ip: Undefined variable.` may be i don't write it correct? At end i put: `done < list.txt` instead of `'ip_list'`