# Quick way to scan from list

Tags: bash

From a bash script how can I quickly find out whether a port 80 is open/listening on a server.

On all workstations is opened daemon, but sometimes it fall, how i can check all $ip from file if port is open, i use this way, but can't find how to automate it. Thank you

```
 nc 10.101.0.13 80 && echo "opened" || echo "closed"
```

I have to separate open one from closed, so i'll have a list of non working what will have to be fixed.

Comment: Why did you accept your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422659/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-in-all-local-network-using-linux) if the answers didn't work for you?

Comment: i have accepted it because it real work how i asked, but don't work if line have strings(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2nd column is not the port number, and you want to check port 80, you should write your script like this:

```
IFS=';'; while read ip others; do nc -zw3 "$ip" 80 && echo "$ip:80 => opened" || echo "$ip:80 =>  closed"; done < list.txt
```

Comment: yes, ray, i fixed it by my self, but i get the error that `Bad : modifier in $ (8).` code is perfect, like i want.. but something is wrong((